# How can I get three items with different heights to display on the same row with css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to build a header for a webpage where I have three objects, but the third object is dropping down below the header that it is in. How can I get the third object (id="cart") to not drop down below the header? The title and cart divs need to have a fixed width, but the options div needs to stretch with the browser.

My HTML:

```
<header>
  <div id="title">
  </div>
  <div id="options">
  </div>
  <div id="cart">
  </div>
</header>
```

My CSS:

```
#title {
    float: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
}
#options {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
#cart {
    height: 40px;
    width: 48px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: set each of their widths to 33%

Comment: also, set display:inline-block on each

Comment: If I set the widths to 33%, The #cart will be a picture with a fixed width, and the title has a fixed width, so I cannot do it this way.

Comment: Just a thought, if you need those specific widths, set the min-width on header to 498px;  I would make it 500px because I like the round number...I know that 150px is the height, but for the sake of the calculation, I used it. The point is to make sure the header is never to small to fit all of the divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `width: calc(100% - 348px);`  for the middle element (which makes it reponsive while the other widths remain fixed) and apply `float: left` to all three elements:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
header > div {
float: left;
}
#title {
    height: 150px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ff5500;
}
#options {
    height: 150px;
    width: calc(100% - 348px);
    background-color: #05f;
}
#cart {
    height: 40px;
    width: 48px;
    float: right;
    background-color: #5f0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="title">
  Title
  </div>
  <div id="options">
  Options
  </div>
  <div id="cart">
  Cart
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I did not know that you could do that (clearly). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Give all of the divs heights and widths, and set their display to inline-block.

Is [this](https://codepen.io/abidishajia/pen/xpomWe) something you have in mind?

```
#title {
  float: none;
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
 #options {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width:300px;
  background-color: #ff5500;
  display: inline-block;
}
 #cart {
   display: block;
   width:300px;
   background-color: blue;
   height: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: This is close, but the options box needs to be responsive. Basically, title and cart will end up with fixed widths and heights, but options needs to stretch depending on the width of the browser. I can't use media queries in this case either.

Answer (score 0):

Set width to all the three div to 33% and set float property to left for all the three div elements or you can set width to 33% for each div element and add display property with value inline-block it will also make the three div to float next to each other.

Comment: Some of the DIVs need to have fixed dimensions while the options div needs to be stretchable.

Comment: then change the width of the div as you want them but total should be 100% or a little less. To create stretchable option div use overflow property or to make it responsive use media query. Or you can use max-width property with values in percentage to make it somewhere responsive without media query. It all depends on which type of page you want.